# how to export volume texture as gltf file from Blender

Tags: animation, export, gltf

I have this cloud/Volume bird(see screenshot) want to export as gltf file with animation. I wonder how can i do export this. Thank you so much. [image]

Comment: Currently, glTF does not support smoke-like volumes such as this.  glTF recently gained support for volumetric attenuation, like colored glass where the color gets deeper where the material is thicker, but such materials always have a well-defined surface.  Blender import/export support has not yet been developed, unfortunately.

Comment: Hi Emackey, Thank you so much for your help. Really appreciate.

Comment: Has this since changed? Blender Manual under Add-Ons>Import-Export>gLTF2.0 it says 'Volume can be exported using a Voume Absorption node ... for volume to be exported some Transmission must be set on Principled BSDF'. And a few other notes. I've tried this and it doesn't seem to work, with a simple cube e.g. and a volume absorption node to create a fog like effect, but I simply see a cube in the gLTF reader. (If it still doesn't work are there any hacks? Like using transparent .png files - this was my first thought but doesn't work quite right either for the purposes of creating 'fog').

Comment: It seems like volumetric attenuation as you've called it is only for translucent materials, with a defined surface - like you said. And doesn't work for clouds and/or fog like materials ... still wondering if there might be a clever hack or work around.

https://www.khronos.org/blog/using-the-new-gltf-extensions-volume-index-of-refraction-and-specular

http://www.cgchannel.com/2021/07/gltf-files-can-now-recreate-accurate-translucent-materials/